# Write on user timeline in facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to let my Facebook App post on user's timeline like this. How to do that with Facebook JavaScript API?

[image]

Comment: I think this option is removed. We can post through popup

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can u supply me with additional information to the solution.